# nodemon not working in windows 10

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I successfully installed nodemon on my local machin, however it is giving me below error message when I run the code.

here is the error detail

```
The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Have you correctly installed the module with the `-g` flag, and set up the path environment variable ? **Edit:** you can also use the command throught NPM. Just create a script with your command inside your package.json and call your script with `npm run scriptName`, and the module executable will be "fetched" from the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem,simple fix first check if path exists on your Environment variable path or not

To check

**Control panel>System>Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables>double-click on PATH**

Now check if you have this PATH ***C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm***

If not, you will see some existing paths, just append to it separating with semicolon. That's it! Worked for me.

add PATH ***C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm*** in  Environment Variables path

Answer (score 5):

Try this for Windows

Open PowerShell and enter the following commands.

A)`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

B)`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

C)`Get-ExecutionPolicy`

D)`Exit`

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  Just had to run powershell as admin.
My error, however,  was a security error. PSSecurityException: UnauthorizedAccess

Answer (score 4):

This works for me: this should limit the policy to the current user.

`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`

Answer (score 4):

i found a way around it , just go inside package.json ( the file that was created after u typed npm init ) and under "scripts" just put `start: "nodemon <filename>"`   and now everytime u type npm start in ur terminal nodemon should start with ur file

Answer (score 2):

I installed nodemon globally and it's started works:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem too.

I installed nodemon in a local directory and tried to run `nodemon index.js`

then I got the above error

I ran `npx nodemon index.js` and the server started successfully

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30279207)

Comment: This solves my problem but WHY?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and nothing worked. Finally after spending hours found the solution.

**If you are using Windows, follow these steps=>**

If you're using powershell, then

Open PowerShell and enter the following lines.

1. Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
2. Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
3. Get-ExecutionPolicy
4. Exit

If you're using command prompt, then

On start menu, search "cmd" , and then right click and run as administrator.
Now you'll have the administrator command prompt running.

Type these instructions =>

1)PowerShell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

2)PowerShell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

3)PowerShell Get-ExecutionPolicy

4)PowerShell Exit

Now Try nodemon [your node app]
Now that your nodemon should be working fine.
Also make sure you have globally installed nodemon
npm install -g nodemon.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps for a windows user:

Open PowerShell and enter:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned (yes)
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted (yes)
Get-ExecutionPolicy
Exit
```

Might be that it still doesn't work in your IDE. If it happens just close and re-open your IDE and try to run it again.

Another option can be that you have to go to your terminal (<kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>) and run:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Those three steps should solve the problem in any case.

Comment: Those steps are not working either

Answer (score 0):

In cmd type npx nodemon server.js and then it will start...

For example,
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`

Answer (score 0):

This was giving me issues as well on Windows 10.
My solution that worked:

1. run:

> npm i nodemon --save-dev

2. In package.json add this (main is whatever file you need to watch):

> "main": "app.js",
> "scripts":{"watch": "nodemon ./app.js"}

3. run:

> npm run watch